# New Site Design!

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see the new design just went live. Congratulations! Thank you for your [valuable design feedback](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2511/software-recommendations-new-site-design).

We have also themed the [twitter account](https://twitter.com/stacksoftrecs) and newsletter template for this site, and adjusted the privilege levels to higher thresholds.

If you see any CSS/styling bugs, please start a new post and tag it with **design** and **bug**.

Congrats again and thank you for being an awesome community!

Oh! And by the way, we have also updated your Chat theme!

Comment: New theme is tremendous!  Well done!

Comment: Congrats, Pawel! Usually it takes me a few weeks at least to get used to design changes. This time I somehow felt home immediately. As for the priv levels: Good that I became mod before that, would have lost my trusted state otherwise #D // PS: I especially like the "tools compass" (my first connotation of the favicon). So thanks again, good job!

Comment: Pawel, not a design bug – but with Meta announcements on chat, the avatar of the announcer (https://cdn.sstatic.net/softwarerecsmeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png) throws a 404 on me. Is it just me?

Comment: "***... adjusted the privilege levels to higher thresholds ...***": is this to way to thank your early adopters reviewers who have been contributing to the quality content of this site ?????????????? How nice! ... Please think of some type of association bonus variation to ***not kick most of those reviewers out*** because of your ridiculous increase of the  privilege thresholds ... or at least make it a granular increase that you announce with enough lead time in advance.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens as disappointing as this might sound, you're looking at it from the wrong end: ***during beta, thresholds were lowered,*** so we all got a "bonus" then for a time, to faster reach our goal (of a stable, mature site). That time just ran out: we're no longer in beta, so normal thresholds apply. Nothing "ridiculous" here. And we all knew this day would come …

Comment: sorry @izzy , I appreciate your comment, but I won't change the "*direction I'm looking at it*". And yes I can understand thresholds do go up. But with this increase, there are now only 7 (resp 8) users left from the top 20 of voters in the close (resp reopen) review queue. That includes the 3 (I believe) mods, who actually don't really need to participate in such queues. Using a granular approach to increase the thresholds, instead of multiply by 4 (repeat: 4!), some might be interested to continue to contribute (eg) via suggesting some edits, etc. At this time "I am not" ...

Comment: *That's* a concern I share: threshold should go "up to normal" one day, but it should also not cut us down in operation that hard (+1 for that argument). As it's the first time for me having participated from early beta stage, I cannot tell if the cut was as hard on other sites, too – and neither whether SE would make exceptions here. But I definitely would welcome them – especially on this background!

Comment: hm, *somebody* seems to have 'liked' my prior comment. Merci anonymous (good to know I'm not the only one). @Izzy : would it make sense to post a meta question here about possibly reconsidering the increased thresholds (to get an idea about what other users think of it)? Tell you what: until these thresholds are revisited somehow, I "go on strike" in the remaining review queue I have enough rep for.

Comment: Read my previous comment on where that "like" came from (pointer: "+1") :) And no, such a request IMHO should go to Meta.SE (for the task). As for "what other users think", I'm pretty sure the majority shares our opinion and would support that.

Comment: @Izzy 404 on avatar might be issue on our side. I will ping someone to take a look at this.

Comment: @Izzy thats what i said: its definitely bug and i've already pinged someone in company to take a look at this. sory for not being clear enough

Comment: @Paweł Sorry, misread it (looking at it now I've no idea how that could happen – need another coffee :) Thanks for checking! Would you also consider some of my style adjustments from below?

Comment: @Izzy thanks for the chat report - I've fixed that bot (and many others).

Comment: @NickCraver Thanks, confimed! Avatar shows up nicely after a reload.

Comment: @Paweł Great job, love the 404 page:)

Answer (score 10):

Looks great Pawel!

Your design is:

- Clear
- Visually appealing
- Simple
- Easy to read
- Reasonably friendly to people with limited eyesight
- Works for people with all types of color blindness
- Low bandwidth

In other words, you've done a great job!

Thanks! :-)

Comment: I am seeing white type on a light gray background and slightly darker gray images on that light gray background.  Barely seeing.  How can you say this is good?

Comment: @JKEngineer Clean your screen or your glasses.  That's not how the design looks for most people.

Comment: It's not my glasses or dirt on my screen.  Here's what I see:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/lxkwm2mfn2zrxkn/New%20Site%20Design%21%20-%20Software%20Recommendations%20Meta%20Stack%20Exchange_000090.jpg?dl=0  I can read the menu only by concentrating on it, not user friendly.  What colors do you see?  This is using Google Chrome, same in Firefox.  In IE, however, the background is dark gray (at the top only), the menus are readable, and there are no visible images in the surround.

Comment: Dropbox is blocked here, so I can't see the image, sorry.  But I can tell you that I see white on a dark blue-gray background for the main site (not meta).  The background is rgb(0,59,80).  Actually, every other pixel is rgb(0,59,79), which is weird.  I have to look at the code to see why that's the case, and if lower bandwidth could be achieved if it rendered as a solid rgb(0,59,80) or rgb(0,59,79).

Comment: I measure the background of the Chrome version as rgb(247,247,247). in IE it varies from 115x3 to 138x3 at the upper portion, with 247x3 on the sides starting at the level of the hairline in the center panel.  None of these are close to the 0,59,79 you cite, which is quite dark and bluish.  The IE version is very readable.

Comment: @JKEngineer Hmmm... weird.  That can't look good.  They have to give me a raise if they want me to figure it out.

Comment: It looks like the IE version paints a top band as a backdrop to the menu items that the other browsers don't.  The sides beyond the text panel are the same in all three.  When they give you the raise, send me half and I will try other browsers.  I'm using Win 7, you?

Comment: Correction to an earlier comment - the surround in IE does have the images as in the other browsers. (Too long ago to edit that comment.)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the raise. ;-)  I checked Opera and it's the same as Chrome.  I think it uses the same rendering engine, so not surprising.

Comment: @JKEngineer What do you mean by "sharing the raise"?  Opera previously used Presto, but for better or worse, they changed it to Webkit.

Comment: It was a small joke...you said you would need a raise to figure it out, I said share the raise and I'll check other browsers, then I checked another browser because you'd "shared the raise".

Comment: @JKEngineer Wow, I was as dense as a neutron star on that one.  To compensate, I just sent you 99% of my raise.

Answer (score 5):

As our Lizard already pointed out: Nice and crisp! Maybe you want to make it even "crisper", so I'll put some of my currently used slight adjustments here, which give a little more contrast while sticking to the color scheme:

```
  /* Make question titles bolder (question list page). */
  #question-mini-list .question-hyperlink,
  #question-header .question-hyperlink,
  #questions .question-hyperlink {
    font-weight: bolder !important;
  }
  /* Darken question excerpt (question list) */
  .excerpt {
    color: #222 !important;
  }

  /* Darken tag text for more contrast */
  .post-tag {
    color: #354044 !important;
  }
  .post-tag:hover { color:white !important;} /* was overwritten by above */

  /* Darken votes text (votes next to questions/answers) */
  .statscontainer .votes, .vote, .vote span, .vote-count-post strong {
    color: black !important;
  }
  /* Better contrast for user-details */
  .started-link, .user-details, .started .reputation-score, .badgecount {
    color: #444 !important;
  }
```

Feel free to pick from these (others: feel free to adapt them into a UserStyle ;)

PS: Also note from my comment above that the avatar of the chat bot (which announced Meta posts in our main room) has gone missing: https://cdn.sstatic.net/softwarerecsmeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png throws a 404 error (not just for me ;)

PPS: The new design seems to have an ad-blocker integrated: what was supposed to show our community-ad for FDroid looks like `<img src="" alt="" title="" width="300" height="250">` (as the hover still works, one can find out via stats which image was supposed to be here).

Answer (score 0):

Overall it is nice.

However, I don't like the link text color for the links that have been visited. It does not stand out very well.

Example:

[image]