# Did the priviledges rise when we graduated?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, privileges, graduation

Before this site graduated, I had roughly 400 rep, and I'm sure I could review First Posts and Late Answers. In fact, I have the Custodian badge for both review types.

I then spent a few months "away", and when I came back the site had graduated. I noticed the "review" link I used to have had disappeared. I didn't think much of it, couldn't quite remember if I had really had it, until I noticed I had the Custodian badges. So I checked it out, and the rep needed is 500 (a rep which I have never achieved). This is in line with Stack Overflow, Super User, etc.

I can't find anywhere that states that the rep either was lower during the beta, or that it increased when the site graduated.

Are my assumptions right?

Comment: Solution: We have to post more good questions/answers, and also upvote more :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not exactly when we graduated, but when we got our "graduated design" (which was a little later). While in beta, levels for a site are significantly lower to help it build up. Once it's graduated and gets its "mature design", that "helping hand" is gone as "the child has risen and can walk on its own feet". Quoting the relevant post, which is [New Site Design!](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2519/185):

> We have also […] adjusted the privilege levels to higher thresholds.

And yes, this is in line with all other "mature sites" – so no specific "punishment" for us, we're just considered "equals" now :)

Comment: Yup, still working my way back up to trusted user on the crypto site. And I'm in the top 10 no less :) Glad to see you have graduated! Hopefully you have a bigger feed than us because it takes ages to get back where I belong (we've got a mod who's got about 7K rep :) ).

Comment: Our mods have ~2, 7 and 10k :)